# How std::bind increases number of arguments passed to a function?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdbind

I am reading a book, and there is below code :

```
mActionBinding[Fire].action = derivedAction<Aircraft>(
std::bind(&Aircraft::fire, _1));
```

the argument that is sent to derived action, will be sent two arguemnts later.

```
template<typename GameObject, typename Function>derived action function 
std::function<void(SceneNode&, sf::Time)> derivedAction(Function fn) 
{
    return [=](SceneNode& node, sf::Time dt) expression 
    {
        assert(dynamic_cast<GameObject *>(&node) != nullptr);

        fn(static_cast<GameObject &>(node), dt);
    };
}
```

the declaration of fire is this which is in Aircraft class:

```
class Aircraft:public SceneNode
{
public:
    void fire()
};
```

I have read some articles about std::bind, but honestly I haven't seen anything like this.this is much more complex.

let me sort my questions:

1-based on my reading, this std::bind has three arguments! the member function, implicit class name and _1. is it true? does this mean, when we invoke it in derivedAction,instead of `static_cast<gameObject &>(node)`, "this" will be sent to it?

2-fire has no argument at all!(except for implicit this), so why _1 give us no error? and how "dt" will be sent to it?

I am a little confused, references gives examples of simple uses, any other information about `std::bind`, will be appreciated.

Comment: @AmiTavory didn't get your comment, what do you mean?

Comment: First argument to `bind`ed member function is instance it will called on, aka _"impicit this"_

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot ok, what about second argument that there is no parameter for it, but jt accepts?

Comment: @AmiTavory i get this, but what about second argument? I mean dt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::bind(&Aircraft::fire, _1)
```

1) There are two arguments passed to `std::bind`. The first argument is `&Aircraft::fire`, a pointer to the member function `Aircraft::fire`. The second argument is `std::placeholders::_1`, found by unqualified lookup due to the presence of a `using namespace std::placeholders` somewhere.

```
fn(static_cast<GameObject &>(node), dt)
```

2) The argument `static_cast<GameObject &>(node)` replaces the `_1` placeholder. `Aircraft::fire` has one parameter, the implicit `this`, so `static_cast<GameObject &>(node)` is supplied as the implicit `this` argument to `Aircraft::fire`. The argument `dt` would replace the `_2` placeholder, but since there is no `_2`, it is ignored.